# How to put eclipse jdt jar libraries in Java Build Path?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath

[image]

I'm trying to use eclipse `jdt`, and I tried to import related modules in java source file.

I have a bunch of errors as the jdt libraries are not in Java Build Path.

[image]

I tried to open `Add Libary -> Plug-in Dependencies`, but it doesn't have the jdt jar files.

[image]

I could use `Add External JARs` to point to all the jar files, but I don't think it's a good idea considering I have to do the same thing over and over again with new projects.

In this case, how to put eclipse jdt jar libraries in Java Build Path? The `java.util.Collection` is found automatically. I guess there might be some easy way to setup so that jdt jar files are found automatically.

Comment: Is your project an eclipse plugin project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I had to use eclipse plugin for using jdt for accessing the files in the workspace, and getting the jar files and such.

However, I found this solution to be very useful for using jdt/ask. The idea is to use string as an input to the jet, and import the related jars for using the jdt APIs.

http://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/a-complete-standalone-example-of-astparser/

I had to open `Configure Build Path`.

[image]

Then, I could select and import all the jar files that I downloaded from the site.

[image]

Now, I am ready to use the libraries.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your project is an eclipse plugin project you can add the jdt as a dependency and the jars will be automatically added to the plugin dependencies
[image: jdt]

Answer (score 0):

In you `Java Build Path` screen, you notice two bottons `Add Variable` and `Add Liberary` below `Add External Jars`. Use those options and define a new variable or new user library; Once done, add the same in the project build path.

For newer project, you can simply reuse the variable/user library.

`java.util.Collection` is found as **it is added as library in your build path(see first item in your screenshot).** I am suggesting to do the same by introducing an `User Library`.