# Download csv file from FTP Server

Tags: java

i am using following code to get csv file from ftp server

but it is working i am place this in servlet i am getting

```
EVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.FTP.Controller.FTPDownload] in context with path [/FTPServer] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.Session
```

can any one suggest me

Comment: Add  jsch.jar to classpath ....download location http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Answer (score 0):

Add the [jsch library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch) on your runtime classpath

Good luck!

**Edited:**

To include a *jar* to classpath:

1. on command line see [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)
2. on Eclipse see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866991/how-to-put-eclipse-jdt-jar-libraries-in-java-build-path)

Comment: sir can tel me how to add jar file at runtime in eclipse ide

Comment: 1. Download jar into your project folder. 2. On "Package explorer" right click on project and select Refresh. 3. Locate the jar file, right click and select "Add to build path".

Comment: Add that information to your answer. Comments are not for adding informations to a answer but to comment on it.